# how to refresh component avoiding infinite looping?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am reading data from a sqlite database , at the same component user may insert data at the same table of that DB , so I'd like to have the ability to insert and display that fresh element just inserted ,  my issue is if I call display function at component will mount that will not display fresh inserted data , if I call that display function from component will receive props that causes infinite loop , could you please help solve this issue
 I am using redux , data store in `props.categes` and the action is `displayFunction()`

here is my code

```
componentWillMount(){
    let cats = [];
        cats = this.props.categes
        let len = this.props.categes.length;
        this.setState({itemsLength : !this.state.itemsLength})
        I18n.locale = this.props.language
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

   if (nextProps.added) {

    this.props.displayFunction()
    cats = this.props.categes
    let len = this.props.categes.length;
     this.setState({itemsLength : true});

    }

}
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({showInput : false, showInput2 : false}) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an infinite loop by adding setState() methods in your component lifecycle methods. The setState() method is still called even if the component is unmounted. To prevent that you can refer to this [link](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-warning-cant-call-setstate-on-an-unmounted-component/)

Also you must check [states and lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: the link example is calling api via axios , I mean he is calling only once , in my example I need to call database with every single update